# Incognito Android browser

Tags: gratis, android, web-browser, privacy

It sounds simple enough - I have some emails which I would not want to be read if someone found my phone, so I get a browser with incognito mode, right?

So, after some googling, I chose [UC Browser Mini for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.uc.browser.en&hl=en).

Then I:

1. start UC browser
2. enter incognito mode
3. go to Gmail
4. get prompted for user name & password and log in
5. exit UC browser
6. start UC browser
7. enter incognito mode
8. go to Gmail
9. see that my user name & password **are already filled in**!

Ok, so much for UC browser.

I don't have time to try them all, so who has personal experience with an Android browser which has a proper incognito mode?

That's all that it has to do - let me access email and leave no traces. Nothing else required (expect that it is gratis).

Comment: I have not used any of them yet myself, but that's a perfect case for my list of [Web Browsers focussed on Privacy](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_webbrowser#group_879) I'd say :) Note that the term "privacy" does not equal "incognito" – the latter is just one aspect of the former, like viruses are only a subsection of malware. So some of the browsers listed there might not have an "incognito mode", but several definitive have. I second *InBrowser*, but you might also wish to check *Javelin* and *Private Browser*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Dolphin Zero

I personally use Dolphin so I have an experience with the browser's abilities. It has a privacy oriented brother called *Zero*. You can install and use Zero side by side with your default browser. Since it is always incognito.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dolphin.browser.zero&hl=en

[image: Logo of Dolphin Zero]

> A streamlined privacy focused browser, Dolphin Zero brings peace of mind to users who wish to keep their personal information as safe as possible by automatically deleting data including browsing history, cache, passwords and cookies that are otherwise saved on the device.
>
> Enabling by default ‘Do Not Track’ functionality to it’s fullest extent, Dolphin Zero will never collect, store or share any of the following information:
>
> - Browser History
> - Form Data
> - Input Data
> - Passwords
> - Cached Data and Files
> - Favicons
> - User Address Book
> - Cookies
> - Location Information

So it's as much privacy oriented as possible and thus is your best bet.

Answer (score 5):

[Firefox](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=org.mozilla.firefox), the on it based [Firefox Focus/Klar](https://www.mozilla.org/firefox/mobile/), [Fennec](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=org.mozilla.fennec_fdroid) or [IceCatMobile](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=org.gnu.icecat) has an Incognito Mode:
[image: Incognito Mode]

and you can also choose which personal data should be deleted (beside the Incognito Mode) when you exit the browser:
[image: Clear private data]

---

### Update

maybe the new [Privacy Browser](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=com.stoutner.privacybrowser.standard) is also worth a look...

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use Chrome? Their mobile browser has incognito and for your purposes, closing windows with emails in them, it seems to fit the bill quite well. Open your notifications panel and there is a 'close all incognito tabs' option so you can close it down with one click.